# Handling PHP headers in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

I am doing a form validating using AJAX. If the user completes the form correctly, it will redirect to another page, else print out errors (plain HTML). 
 **For example:**
If there is an error in the form, the PHP file echos:

```
There is an error!
```

If there aren't any errors, the PHP file executes:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/successful"); exit();
```

But in AJAX, I am only handling for the plain HTML response:

```
success: function(response) {
_desireHTMLelment.innerHTML = response;
}
```

I know there is a way using `json_encode()`, however, I still cannot classify plain HTML and `JSON`. 
Are there any ways I can do this? Thanks for any support! 
**Edit:** I am using Vanilla JavaScript 
This is how the system works: 
User fills in the form => AJAX sends requests => PHP processes the request => Either returns an plain HTML error or redirects the page => AJAX receives the response, classify whether it is an error or HTML error => Find a correct way to handle the response

Comment: Do the redirect in javascript based on the response. So you would need to send a response from php instead of using a `header()` redirect.

Comment: @jeroen I know, I used `json_encode` for this, however, I don't know how to classify it with plain HTML

Comment: Or just submit the form if the ajax does not give errors

Comment: @mplungjan, how to check if the PHP doesn't send any errors? That's the thing

Comment: @WebDegBrian You shouldn't. Either send back plain text or send back json; not a different kind of response depending on the situation. You could send the html in the json as well.

Comment: @jeroen, thanks, good idea, maybe I will try that

Comment: `success: function(response) {
 if (response.error) { _desireHTMLelment.innerHTML = response.message }
 else $("form").submit();
}`

Comment: @mplungjan can you please post it as an answer and add explainations to it?

Comment: Is it imperative that you do ajax/server validation? You do  need to check on the server, but to submit the form, you can start with client side validation and then allow the submission if no errors

Comment: @mplungjan, let me have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quentin mentioned, browsers automatically follow the `Location` header and redirect the page, in which case your Ajax response will contain the content of the new page and you will not be able to access the `Location` header because it was lost and replaced by the content of the new page. You can use a different name for your header.

It seems from your code that you're using jQuery, not JavaScript Vanilla. You can access the header in jQuery like this:

```
success: function(response, status, request){
    var url = request.getResponseHeader('RedirectURL'); //RedirectURL: your header's name.
}
```

In JavaScript Vanilla, use the [`getAllResponseHeaders()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders) function of the `XMLHttpRequest` object to get the header:

```
var headers = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

But unlike jQuery, you'll have to split and process the headers by yourself.

Once you get the url from the header, you can use:

```
location.replace(url);
```

This simulate a redirect. If you want to simulate a link click, use:

```
location.href = url;
```

Alternatively, you can send the URL in the response instead of the header. If it always starts with http, you can do something like:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response.substring(0, 4) == "http") {
        location.href = response;
    } else {
       _desireHTMLelment.innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

Or you can flag it like this and look for the flag:

```
RedirectURL: http://example.com/successful
```

Or you can make it a JSON object:

```
{"RedirectURL": "http://example.com/successful"}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use `request.getAllResponseHeaders().trim().split(/[\r\n]+/);` to get the array of headers

Comment: Yes, that's what you should be using, so what's the problem?

Comment: I am testing on my website. If it is correct, I will vote for your answer

Comment: You can't access the `Location` header like that.

Comment: @Quentin, sorry, what's the problem?

Comment: @WebDegBrian — Browsers silently follow redirects

Comment: @Quentin, yeah, when I logged out the array of headers, I cannot see where is the "Location"

Comment: Yes, Quentin is right. I didn't pay attention that the name of your header is standard redirection header. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sure, i will reply you in a second

Comment: Yeah, both of your solutions work for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If the browser recieves a `Location` header in the HTTP response, then it will follow the redirect and fetch the document you are being redirected to.

There is no way to read the redirect response with JS.

---

There are two possible outcomes from your request:

1. The response contains the text `There is an error!`
2. The response redirects the browser which gets a new response which doesn't contain that text

So, to tell which of the two cases you have: Search the response text for `There is an error!`.

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response.indexOf("There is an error!" == -1) {
        // Handle the error
    } else {
       _desireHTMLelment.innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

---

That said, a better approach would be to change the server side code so it provides a clear API instead of trying to scrape HTML for the data.

Comment: This the the way how the system works: The user fills in the form, AJAX sends it to a specified PHP file, PHP processes it, either returns an plain HTML or redirects the page. But if I use AJAX for this, it will only redirect a part of my document

Comment: You really should just fix your server side script to stop returning basic html or a redirect, and just have it ALWAYS return a json object with directions on how to handle the result for ajax. If you are wanting to double-use a script where someone has JS off (morons), then always pass a variable with the ajax request, so you can branch on HOW you return data out (either json, or basic html/redirect).

Comment: @IncredibleHat, thanks, I will try to follow your instructions

Comment: You misunderstood the question. In the first of the two possible outcomes that you mentioned, the response may contain one of several error messages, so there is no way to detect it unless you flag it (e.g. `ERR: There is an error!`), or you make it a JSON object. As for the second possible outcome, your solution is too wasteful of resources. Why would you let Ajax redirect to the page, and then you detect that and redirect again? (You assigned the result to an element, but the OP wanted to redirect, so you'll need to replace the entire page with the result).